# MVC Layout Header - Ajax updates

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, fiddler

On my layout page I have a header bar similar to stack overflow which needs to be refreshed from time to time (notifications, etc).

My approach was to create a timer interval :

```
setInterval(onTimerCheckAccountSummary, 60000);
```

This is my ajax call that runs every minute :

```
function onTimerCheckAccountSummary() {
    //Get Notification List
    $.ajax({
        global: false,
        url: '/Home/HeaderSummary',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#header-summary').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Meanwhile I opened fiddler and noticed that each call is making a new request.

Is this the way it should be done? Is there anyway to do it only on one session? I am asking this because stack overflow also checks from time to time for new data and I don't see a bunch of requests on fiddler.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

A request is simply a POST/GET communication. The requests are still within the same session context. Here is a [similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127842/asp-net-ajax-asynch-request-has-separate-session)

Comment: I don't get it, because stackoverflow is checking for new updates all the time and I cannot see anything on fiddler.

Comment: Actually, I don't see the updates until I reload the page... That would imply that these types of notifications aren't being used here.

Comment: Yes you can see for example : "A new comment was posted", "A new answer was posted". Those notifications appear a lot on Q&A pages.